# How to refactor code using the State monad in order to increase modularity by adding more functions?

Tags: haskell, monads, record, clash

I am trying to get the hang of monads. I figured it would be good practice to play with the state monad.

Using the UART Rx from [CLaSH](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/clash-prelude-0.10.14/docs/CLaSH-Examples.html):

```
-- UART RX Logic
data RxReg
  = RxReg
  { _rx_reg        :: BitVector 8
  , _rx_data       :: BitVector 8
  , _rx_sample_cnt :: Unsigned 4
  , _rx_cnt        :: Unsigned 4
  , _rx_frame_err  :: Bool
  , _rx_over_run   :: Bool
  , _rx_empty      :: Bool
  , _rx_d1         :: Bit
  , _rx_d2         :: Bit
  , _rx_busy       :: Bool
  }

makeLenses ''RxReg

uartRX r@(RxReg {..}) rx_in uld_rx_data rx_enable = flip execState r $ do
  -- Synchronise the async signal
  rx_d1 .= rx_in
  rx_d2 .= _rx_d1
  -- Uload the rx data
  when uld_rx_data $ do
    rx_data  .= _rx_reg
    rx_empty .= True
  -- Receive data only when rx is enabled
  if rx_enable then do
    -- Check if just received start of frame
    when (not _rx_busy && _rx_d2 == 0) $ do
      rx_busy       .= True
      rx_sample_cnt .= 1
      rx_cnt        .= 0
    -- Star of frame detected, Proceed with rest of data
    when _rx_busy $ do
      rx_sample_cnt += 1
      -- Logic to sample at middle of data
      when (_rx_sample_cnt == 7) $ do
        if _rx_d1 == 1 && _rx_cnt == 0 then
          rx_busy .= False
        else do
          rx_cnt += 1
          -- start storing the rx data
          when (_rx_cnt > 0 && _rx_cnt < 9) $ do
            rx_reg %= replaceBit (_rx_cnt - 1) _rx_d2
          when (_rx_cnt == 9) $ do
            rx_busy .= False
            -- Check if End of frame received correctly
            if _rx_d2 == 0 then
              rx_frame_err .= True
            else do
              rx_empty     .= False
              rx_frame_err .= False
              -- Check if last rx data was not unloaded
              rx_over_run  .= not _rx_empty
  else do
    rx_busy .= False
```

How would I go about moving the `when` logic to their own functions? I have been playing with this for a little bit, but the lenses seem to be causing issues.

```
Could not deduce Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState from .=
```

I am think there is a function [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html)

That I am missing.

I would want to do something like

```
newFun = when (not _rx_busy && _rx_d2 == 0) $ do
         rx_busy       .= True
         rx_sample_cnt .= 1
         rx_cnt        .= 0
```

I would think there would be a function like `execState` that I need.

So my questions are,

- What should I be using?
- What does that function do that allows it to compose with other functions?
- If monads are just composing why cant I have the `when` in a function without an execState type function?
- What other ways could I increase the modularity of this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your definition of `newFun`

```
newFun = when (not _rx_busy && _rx_d2 == 0) $ do
         rx_busy       .= True
         rx_sample_cnt .= 1
         rx_cnt        .= 0
```

you are trying to refer to `_rx_busy` and `_rx_d2`, which are record fields of the type `RxReg`. In `uartRX`, the first argument is an `RxReg`, and the RecordWildCards language extension is used to bind all the field names by matching the argument with the pattern `RxReg{..}`. So you will either need to pass `r` itself, or at least `_rx_busy` and `_rx_d2`, from `uartRX` to `newFun`; i.e. either have

```
newFun busy d2 = when (not busy && d2 == 0) $ do
    ...
```

or

```
newFun RxReg{..} = when (not _rx_busy && _rx_d2 == 0) $ do
    ...
```